# Zopheridae Super Shell

Tags: science-based, biology, weapons, insects, zoology

The Zopheridae is a subfamily of beetles that are known for their super hard exoskeletons. In order to stick and insect-pin in them, you need a drill to get it in them. You also cannot crush them just by stepping on them.

Now let’s say we supersize the Beetle to 20ft long and ignored all the other problems with that, how strong could this shell be and could it even go as far to handle elephant guns or tank fire?

Comment: There is a lot of little things that factor into the Ironclad beetle's exoskeleton, which mess with scaling up, I found a paper that goes into some research done on it: https://search.proquest.com/openview/48d637569b7a72c5e360ff983e7dd0a0

Answer (score 7):

The answer may well be that the armour on the beetle is actually *weaker*, not stronger as you scale up.

The reason for this is that things like beetle carapaces get their strength from 3 factors; the material that make up the carapace, the thickness of the carapace, and the **shape** of the carapace.

Have you ever noticed how many arches there are in older churches, castles and cathedrals? This is not an architectural fancy; those arches help distribute the weight of the building (particularly the roof) and concentrate it into the pillars. The arches were one of the first engineering inventions that allowed us to build larger structures that were mostly hollow inside, allowing us to gather people in numbers and put them inside large structures.

Your beetle doesn't have internal pillars, so the rounded shape of his carapace has some bearing on the strength, and it won't scale up. Depending on the material used, it may well weaken as that rounded shape increases in size.

Sure, the material of the carapace will get thicker, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it will get stronger, especially if the shape doesn't support that.

In material science, there are two measures of the strength of a material; compressive strength (how much force can the material withstand before deforming inwardly) and tensile strength (how much force can the material withstand before being torn apart).

Concrete, for example, has very good compressive strength, but almost no tensile strength. This is why we put metal reinforcing in concrete pads and the like; without it the concrete would crack underfoot. Not because our standing on it compresses it, but rather because standing in the middle of the pad would actually *stretch* the concrete supported at the edges by us bowing it.

I don't know what material your beetle's carapace is made from, but if it has a similar imbalance between compressive and tensile strength, increasing the scale of the beetle doesn't necessarily increase the strength of the carapace. In many cases, it would actually weaken it.

Oh, and your beetle would die by the way, because insects don't have lungs. A beetle that large couldn't get O<sub>2</sub> into its core through atmospheric absorption. I know you said to ignore these problems, but in this one particular case, it's relevant.

You see, a beetle's carapace is porous to some degree. It HAS to be, otherwise the beetle would suffocate. That means that even if you ignore the problem of insect size on O<sub>2</sub> saturation for the beetle, you can't ignore the fact that a porous carapace would mean even more weakness for the armour strength. In this case, it would probably weaken tensile strength, meaning that the larger beetle is even MORE likely to have a weaker carapace that its conventionally sized brother.

Sometimes, good things really DO only come in small packages.

Comment: Of course...you could always jack the O2 concentration up to where it was back in the days of giant dragonflies...  :)

Comment: @RonJohn outstanding. :) Only problem I can see is that if the carapace material is like Kevlar, it then wouldn't be able to withstand the heat of all those forest fires that result...

Comment: I appreciate all the time a detail you put in the answer and I have one more question, say you just upped the size of the shell and did nothing else to the creature to modify it for being so large. It doesn't really matter to me if the beetle will survive or not. Thank you very much

Comment: Well in that case, it's a simple lever problem. The carapace will deform more readily from impacts because the shape of the shell hasn't changed, but the arc describing the curvature of the beetle is now larger, meaning that at any point on the carapace the surface is *flatter*, making it less resistant to a bowing pressure. if you hit a tight arc with a hammer for instance, the curve allows for the bowing pressure to be more readily transferred to areas less perpendicular to the hammer strike. With larger arcs, the surface is closer to perpendicular to the strike, allowing it to bow.